# Xamarin forms IOS app size increases from 42.8 MB to 108 MB after certification

Tags: xamarin.ios, size, xamarin.forms

My app size increases from 42.8 MB to 108 MB after certification, according to IOS documentation

> When your app is approved for the App Store, it is encrypted with DRM and recompressed. The encryption and DRM will increase the file size. The exact size of the increase varies, but can be significant if the binary contains a large proportion of contiguous zeros. The final size for your app after the encryption has been added cannot be determined or guaranteed in advance.

What does it mean by

> can be significant if the binary contains a large proportion of contiguous zeros

I wanted to set Link behavior to "Link all assemblies" but my app crashes if I set that. 
Please suggest me best way to reduce size.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit the app the code is compressed, this succeeds because compression relies on repeated patterns that exist in code. When Apple signs the app it first encrypts the app code and since encrypted code is essentially random data there are no patterns to compress and the size increases.

Comment: My first version with "link all assemblies" just increased to 70 MB but this version increased to 108 MB which makes me worry as users cannot download on cellular data